# How to create custom usergroups in Joomla

Tags: joomla

Is there a way to create custom user groups in Joomla?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that I found the answer myself. 
You need to install a component like NoixACL. Or wait till Joomla v1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Community Builder](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/210/details), that's the one that everyone uses.

Answer (score 0):

There was a really good ACL component that i used on a site a while back that integrated nicely with paypal

http://www.opensource-excellence.com

they have a really good horizontal user control system that easily integrates with joomla